# How to create javascript call dynamically in c# , .asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

net , c#. I am calling a javascript by using following code . `

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

       $("[src='/pinterest/portals/0/Images/about-person3.jpg']").pinit();
       $("[src='/pinterest/portals/0/Images/about-us-group.jpg']").pinit();
    });
    </script>
```

`My c# code is`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<br />
<img ID="ImageZoom" runat="server" src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %> '  style="display: inline; height:auto; left: 0pt; top: 0pt; width:auto;" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageId") %> '  /> 

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>`
```

if i add more images i should call javascript for all images .

Answer (score 1):

You're question is vague at best, but I think this is what you're looking for:

1. Assign a class to the images that you want to call `pinit()` on.
2. Use jQuery's [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to retrieve the appropriate objects.

   ```
   <img ID="ImageZoom" class='pinitPlease' runat="server" ... />

   $(function () {
       $(".pinitPlease").pinit();
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to zoom images that are located in /pinterest/portals/0/Images/

you can adapt your [jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select those imgages that start with that path

$("[src^='/pinterest/portals/0/Images/']").pinit();

Answer (score 0):

All your images will have the word "ImageZoom" in their ID, so you can make a selector by that and find all images together.

```
$("[id*='ImageZoom']").pinit();
```